# Is there an inversish method for `Array#include?`?

Tags: ruby

I've always wondered if there is an inverse method for `include?`.
So that given:

```
str = "a"
ary = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I can check if the string is in the array rather than if the array contains the string. Something like:

```
str.in?(ary)
```

I can't think of a situation where this is necessary, but often I think from that direction rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such method in Ruby itself, but there is such method in Rails - [`Object#in`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/in%3F)